# How to upload zip/rar file to google drive using Google app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jszip

How to upload zip/rar file to google drive using Google app script? I tried these code below .gs in google app script:

```
function doPost(e) {

    try {
    var data = e.parameter.fileContent;
    var filename = e.parameter.filename;
    var email = e.parameter.email;
    var name = e.parameter.name;
    var result=uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,filename,name,email,e);
    return redirect();
    } catch(error) { 
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
    }

    var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

    function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
    }

function record_data(e,fileUrl) {
    try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('datasheet'); // select the responses sheet
    
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
    
    if(headers[i].length > 0 && headers[i] == "Zip-Link") {
    row.push(fileUrl); // add data to row
    }
    else if(headers[i].length > 0) {
    row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
    }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    }
    catch(error) {
    Logger.log(e);
    }
    finally {
    return;
    }
    
}
    
function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email,e) {
    try {
    var dropbox = "dropbox";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
        
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
    bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
    blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
    var file = folder.createFolder([date, email].join("--")).createFile(blob);
        
    var fileUrl=file.getUrl();
        
    record_data(e,fileUrl); //record data into my excel
        
    } catch (f) {
    return ContentService // return json success results
    .createTextOutput(
    JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
    "data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
}

function redirect() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + REDIRECT_URL + "\";</script>"
  ); 
}
```

I don't know if it is Utilities.base64Decode goes wrong or what, cuz I can upload the file but it gives me an error of broken file or wrong format after I tried to download and open it, could anyone tell me what is my mistake??

For addition to how I get the data URL of the files and zip it together:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {

    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
  
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
  
    var blob = new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
    return blob;
  }

function getfile() {
    var zip = new JSZip();
  
    for(let i = 0; i < testpush.length; i++){
    
        var aFileName = "image"+i+1+".jpg";
        var aContent = dataURItoBlob(testpush[i]); //content of file
    
        //put files onto a folder
        zip.folder("Image_folder").file(aFileName, aContent)
    }
    zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"})
    .then(function (content) {
        fileData = "data:application/zip;base64,"+content;
        document.getElementById('fileContent').value = fileData;
    });
}
```

The Script of how I send data to google drive in HTML:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="form-uploadForm" data-name="uploadForm" method="post" action="MyGoogleAppScirptLink" class="buyerform">
  <textarea placeholder="Example Text"
  id="fileContent" name="fileContent" data-name="fileContent" class="input" 
  spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  <label class="img_label" for="placeholder_input">
      <div class="plus"></div>
   </label>
  <input type='file' id="placeholder_input" class="hidden" accept="image/*" onchange='openFiles(event)' multiple>
  <input id='sumbit-bill-now' class='submit-display-none' value='check it' type='button' onclick='getfile();' />
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you call `uploadFileToGoogleDrive` and with what parameters?

Comment: I just updated the `doPost()` function of .gs file, thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: In order to confirm your upload process, can you provide the script for uploading the file to `doPost`?

Comment: @Tanaike First I choose the pics and upload it to the browser using FileReader() to read pics as dataurl and 
convert it to blob and 
zip it using Jszip and
get the dataurl from Jszip then
use document.getElementById('fileContent') to set value = to DataUrl of Zip file and
submit the form to google app script to doPost();

Comment: @Tanaike Btw I just find out once i set
 `document.getElementById('fileContent') to set value = to DataUrl of Zip file` 
the browser and the site will stop working without any error. Any Idea?

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. Unfortunately, from your additional information, I couldn't understand about `openFiles(event)`. I deeply apologize for this.